# How to get ID of closest checkbox item by clicking on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<div class="todo-task"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id=' checkbox1' /> 
    <label for='checkbox1 '> hellooooo <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> 
    </label> 
</div>
```

When i click the span item , i want the id value of the checkbox . How  can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse to a known parent that also contains the checkbox, find the checkbox then get the ID attribute.

```
$('span.todo-remove').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.todo-task').find('input:checkbox').attr('id');
    // do something with id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate up then search

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.todo-task');//navigate up
  var input = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]');//search
  var id = input.attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-task">
  <input type="checkbox" id=' checkbox1' />
  <label for='checkbox1 '>hellooooo <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete">in span</span> 
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:
`$('.todo-remove').closest('.todo-task').find('input').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [.parent()-method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) navigates to the `label`-level and then the [.siblings()-method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selects the siblings that match the selector. Finally you can use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the actual value.

```
$(".todo-remove").on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().siblings("input[type='checkbox']").attr("id");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d0cekb6p/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
      $('.todo-remove').on('click', function() {
          var checkID = $(this).closest('div.todo-task').find(':checkbox').prop('id');
          console.log( checkID );
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-task"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id=' checkbox1' /> 
    <label for='checkbox1 '> hellooooo <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete">X</span> 
    </label> 
</div>
```